# multiple parameter in filter in rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am passing 2 parameter in filter and its not working. can someone help on this.

```
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle1 + "')/Items?
$filter=Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"'
&$select=Application_x0020_Path" and Application eq AAA;
```

Below line with one parameter is working fine

```
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle1 + "')/Items?$filter=Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"'&$select=Application_x0020_Path";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle1 + "')/Items?$select=Application_x0020_Path&$filter=Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"'and Application eq 'AAA'"
```

Comment: thanks it works with small change of ('AAA').
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle1 + "')/Items?$select=Application_x0020_Path&$filter=Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"'and Application eq 'AAA' "

Comment: Yes i will change my answer. You can mark it as answer if it helped you

Comment: @Brishal Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

Modify your endpoint as below (check for double/single quote  ):

```
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle1 + "')/Items?
$filter=Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"' and Application eq 'AAA'
&$select=Application_x0020_Path"
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: Please ensure that you are using the internal column names for your filter operations

Comment: also you can try it as `$filter=((Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"') and (Application eq 'AAA')`

Comment: yes internal name is same. tried with below but still not working.
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle1 + "')/Items?$filter=((Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"') and (Application eq 'AAA')&$select=Application_x0020_Path";

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this,


var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle1 + "')/Items?
    $filter=Project_x0020_code eq '"+ Project_code +"' and Application eq 'AAA'
    &$select=Application_x0020_Path";
```